# ios How does facebook and instagram update those notification numbers (eg message, like, or friend)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, push-notification, instagram

Was wondering how facebook and instagram gets their notification notices whenever you're using the app. eg. Message number on facebook, Somebody followed you on instagram, etc. Is it using push notifications? Or just regular executions of an api? It seems expensive to do push notifications cuz of the monthly fee of a VPS. (Based off of this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

I wanted to know any other options that I can use as I only need something witht the same effect as facebook or instagram.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They do use push notification for updates of friends/follow/IM.

The cost of using Push Notifications is something big company can easily afford and it is nothing compared to how much money a iOS app can make to the dev.

Comment: how can you be sure that it is push notification ?

Comment: two ways to be sure 1) if you receive Same notification when app is not running..then it can be only push notification.. 2) update to specific user are done through push notification..a app would not continuously query server for update..since it is just waste of resources

Comment: well, i just wanted something where there's a "number" marked on the icons eg. message icon in fb and like icon in instagram. Those doesn't seem like push notifications. As far as I know push notifications are popups that notifies the user if the phone is locked or if the app is not used.